# Passing boolean parameters from xml in testNG

Tags: java, xml, testing, testng

To send strings in the XML as parameters the following code would be used

(XML)

```
parameter name="firstName" value="John"
```

(Java)

```
 @Parameters ({"firstName"})
```

However, how would you send a boolean value?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the type of the argument to Boolean

```
 @Parameters({"bval"})
    @Test()
    public void test1(Boolean val){
        if(val)
            System.out.println("I am true");
        else
            System.out.println("I am false");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, any Java **primitive** and **String** types are able to be transformed from XML to Java and vice versa automatically.

```
@Parameters({"bval"})
@Test()
public void test1(boolean val){
...
}
```